# How to select elements that does not contain data (insensitive way)?

Tags: jquery

I use that:

```
$("#userList").not("[data-username*='john']").toggle()
```

And want it to run it for JOHN as well (insensitive)

I tried with the 'i' flag, but this raises an error

```
$("#userList").not("[data-username*='john' i]").toggle()
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Your first code block works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/de38j478/ And according to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#casesens), it should work. (But I know that flag is a thing, just trying to remember what triggers case-sensitivity...)

Comment: [jQuery does not support case-insensitive attribute comparisons](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278).  You'll need to write your own.

Comment: Try to use filter function; **$("#userList").filter(function(a){ var b=$(a).data("username")+""; return b.indexOf("JHON")<0;})**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet are running case insensitive:

```js
 $(".userList[data-username='john' i]").show()
$(".userList:not([data-username='john' i])").show()
```

```css
.userList{display:none;}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class=userList>.userList[]</div>
    <div class=userList data-username=john>.userList[john]</div>
    <div class=userList data-username=John>.userList[John]</div>
    <div class=userList data-username=mike>.userList[mike]</div>
```

**EDIT**

and to NOT, use the selector `:not()`

```js
$(".userList:not([data-username='john' i])").show()
```

```css
.userList{display:none;}
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class=userList>.userList[]</div>
        <div class=userList data-username=john>.userList[john]</div>
        <div class=userList data-username=John>.userList[John]</div>
        <div class=userList data-username=mike>.userList[mike]</div>
```

Just adjust to fit your needs

Comment: But I need these that DOES NOT CONTAIN !